# Function returning wrong value in lpc824

Tags: c++, function, return, lpc, lpcxpresso

I am working on porting an application running on `Arduino Mega` to `LPC824`. The following piece of code is working differently for both the platforms.

```
/**
 * Calculation of CMAC
 */
void cmac(const uint8_t* data, uint8_t dataLength) {

    uint8_t trailer[1] = {0x80};
    uint8_t bytes[_lenRnd];
    uint8_t temp[_lenRnd];

    memcpy(temp, data, dataLength);

    concatArray(temp, dataLength, trailer, 1);
    dataLength ++;

    addPadding(temp, dataLength);

    memcpy(bytes, _sk2, _lenRnd);

    xorBytes(bytes,temp,_lenRnd);

    aes128_ctx_t ctx;
    aes128_init(_sessionkey, &ctx);

    uint8_t* chain = aes128_enc_sendMode(bytes, _lenRnd, &ctx, _ivect);
    Board_UARTPutSTR("chain\n\r");
    printBytes(chain, 16, true);

    memcpy(_ivect, chain, _lenRnd);

    //memcpy(_ivect, aes128_enc_sendMode(bytes,_lenRnd,&ctx,_ivect), _lenRnd);

    memcpy(_cmac,_ivect, _lenRnd);

    Board_UARTPutSTR("Initialization vector\n\r");
    printBytes(_ivect, 16, true);
}
```

I am expecting a value like `{0x5d, 0xa8, 0x0f, 0x1f, 0x1c, 0x03, 0x7f, 0x16, 0x7e, 0xe5, 0xfd, 0xf3, 0x45, 0xb7, 0x73, 0xa2}` for the `chain` variable. But the follow function is working differently. The print inside the function has the correct value which I want `({5d, 0xa8, 0x0f, 0x1f, 0x1c, 0x03, 0x7f, 0x16, 0x7e, 0xe5, 0xfd, 0xf3, 0x45, 0xb7, 0x73, 0xa2})`.

But when the function returns `chain` is having a different value, compared to what I am expecting, I get the following value for `chain` `{0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x10, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0xd5, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xd7, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}`

Inside the function, the result is correct. But it returns a wrong value to the function which called it. Why is it happening so ?

```
uint8_t* aes128_enc_sendMode(unsigned char* data, unsigned short len, aes128_ctx_t* key,
        const unsigned char* iv) {

    unsigned char tmp[16];
    uint8_t chain[16];
    unsigned char c;
    unsigned char i;

    memcpy(chain, iv, 16);

    while (len >= 16) {
        memcpy(tmp, data, 16);

        //xorBytes(tmp,chain,16);
        for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            tmp[i] = tmp[i] ^ chain[i];
        }

        aes128_enc(tmp, key);

        for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            //c = data[i];
            data[i] = tmp[i];
            chain[i] = tmp[i];
        }

        len -= 16;
        data += 16;

    }

    Board_UARTPutSTR("Chain!!!:");
    printBytes(chain, 16, true);

    return chain;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A good start with an issue like this is to delete as much as you can while reproducing the error, with a minimal code example the answer is typically clear.  I have done that for you here.

```
uint8_t* aes128_enc_sendMode(void) {
    uint8_t chain[16];
    return chain;
}
```

The chain variable is a local to the function, it ceases to be defined once the function exists. Accessing a pointer to that variable causes undefined behaviour, don't do it.

In practice the pointer to the array still exists and points to an arbitrary block of memory. This block of memory is no longer reserved and can be overwritten at any time.

I suspect it works for the AVR because it is a simple 8 bit chip and that piece of memory was sitting unmolested by the time you used it. The ARM would have used greater optimisations, possibly running the full array on registers, so the data doesn't survive the transition.

tldr; You need to malloc() any arrays that you want to live past the function's exit. Be careful, malloc and embedded systems go together like diesel and styrofoam, it gets messy real quick.